# Find rows without matching second field for given constants in first field

Tags: ms-access

Consider an example table with two string fields `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`.

For a given `Lastname == Smith`, I find to expect a row with another given `Lastname == Johnson` and identical Firstname.

How can Find rows for which this isn't the case, i.e. `Lastname == Smith, Firstname == Julia` exists, but `Lastname == Johnson, Firstname == Julia` does not?.

Sample Data:

```
FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
Jane, Smith
John, Smith
Blake, Smith
Jane, Johnson
Blake, Johnson
```

Query so far:
`SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_NAME, COUNT(*) AS c, FIRST_NAME FROM Table1 GROUP BY FIRST_NAME) WHERE c = 1`

What I'd like to get:

```
John, Smith
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing us a sample set of data and the results you are expecting.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want the following (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=2b31da9b9fb6ad12cb5610dfd6a60d05)):

Create and populate table - using SQL Server 2012 as this will most closely emulate Access. I've used my own SQL style largely modelled on [this](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/).

```
CREATE TABLE source_table
(
  first_name VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL, 
  last_name  VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT f_l_uq UNIQUE (first_name, last_name)
);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO source_table
  (first_name, last_name)
VALUES
  ('Jane', 'Smith'),
  ('John', 'Smith'),
  ('Blake', 'Smith'),
  ('Jane', 'Johnson'),
  ('Blake', 'Johnson');
```

I've put a `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination of (first_name, last_name) because it makes sense - if this really is your entire table, you could make it the `PRIMARY KEY` - if there is/are (a) `PK` field(s) as part of a table with more fields, then just add this constraint.

If you do have duplicate first and last names combined (dupes), then you can just add a `DISTINCT` clause to your `SELECT` and this will give you unique values for your desired result(s) - included in the fiddle, not shown here.

then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT if there are dupes!
  s1.first_name,
  s1.last_name
FROM source_table s1
WHERE s1.last_name = 'Smith'
AND s1.first_name NOT IN
(
  SELECT first_name FROM source_table s2
  WHERE last_name != 'Smith'
);
```

Result:

```
first_name  last_name
      John      Smith
```

Et voilà - the desired result!

p.s. [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is a better tool that SQLFiddle - more servers (see dropdown) and more functionality (see the [`compare link`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&rdbms2=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f)) for example!

p.p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM sourcetable t1
LEFT JOIN sourcetable t2 ON t1.Firstname = t2.Firstname 
                        AND t1.Lastname = 'Smith'
WHERE t2.Firstname  IS NULL
```

?

Comment: It's just one table.

Comment: @Xaser it's two copies of one table.

Comment: Ah, I get it. nevertheless, [doesn't seem to do what I want](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7dabb1/2).